# CSS: new line above first line?

Tags: css

In my horizontal menu (done with ul + floated li) the li elements are shown in the next line (below the first line) if they are too many to fit in the current width. Example:

**first | second | third**

**fourth | fifth**

That´s normal. But to how can I accomplish to have the next line **above** the first one? Example:

**fourth | fifth**

**first | second | third**

Since I am doing a responsive layout, I cannot simply define this order statically as it should happen automatically only in case the window width is too small to fit all items in one row.

Thanks in advance,
Dirk

Comment: Do you have the html / css that displays it in the right order?

Answer (score 1):

If browser compatibility isn't an absolute requirement, try `flex`:

```
ul {
    display:flex;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    flex-flow: row wrap-reverse;
    -ms-flex-flow: row wrap-reverse;
}
```

The above will work in IE10. You'll have to look up the -moz- and -webkit- versions, they keep changing on me...

Comment: Firefox (Gecko) Not Supported, Internet Explorer Not supported, Safari Not supported. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap

Comment: @l'L'l [View this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6PP82/) in IE10 and tell me it's not supported.

Comment: Maybe you should, before downvoting people who do ;)

Comment: @Kolink: Thanks, it really works in IE10 but browser compatibility IS a requirement. Although having played around with various attributes linked in the flex-wrap page you provided, nothing worked at least with FF21. And even if it would, I´d wish for a more generic solution. I didn´t expect this to be such a sophisticated request :-(

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, if your website is for IE, you could have a look at `writing-mode` property, which allows you to set all kinds of layout flows, including the "bottom to top". If you're interested in this, have a look at this [blog post](http://www.zachleat.com/web/css3-text-writing-mode/) and this [demo](http://www.zachleat.com/test/writing-mode/).

But the "safest" solution for you here should be javascript based. You could use jQuery.

So let's say you menu is:

```
    <div class="menu" id="menu">

      <div id="optional-row"></div>             <!-- movable items container -->

      <div id="main-row">
        <div class="item">elem1</div>
        <div class="item">elem2</div>
        <div class="item">elem3</div>
        <div class="item">elem4</div>
        <div class="item movable">elem5</div>   <!-- movable item -->
        <div class="item movable">elem6</div>   <!-- movable item -->
      </div>

    </div>
```

As you can see I've defined some elements as movable by adding them the "movable" class.
Now, if my `window.width()` is too small, I can do this

```
<!-- don't forget including jquery before -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var movables = $(".movable");
  // hiding all movable elements
  movables.hide();                  
  movables.each(function(i){
    // inserting them in the optional row
    $("#optional-row").append(($(this).html()));
  }); 
</script>
```

Here is a [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bImuJ)

Comment: Interesting idea. I will try to use this as the basis to take into account the width of each movable item and the container element and compute the current width to find which items still need to be shifted to the upper row. Could be quite lengthy since there could be the case where a third line is necessary. Anyway, thanks for the idea!